# std::vector<T*> vs std::vector<T> for 64-bit T

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, stl

In a 3D geometry engine code I read that:

**`std::vector<GA_Offset*>` seems wrong, `GA_Offset` is merely a 64-bit `integer`. 
`std::vector<GA_Offset>` would be better.**

where `GA_Offset` aka `long int` is a, possibly, non-contiguous offset to an element in a geometry structure. `GA_Offsets` remain constant even if an element prior to it is deleted, but will be invalidated if an element is inserted prior to it, or if the element list is defragmented.

In my short C++ experience I've learned that references and pointers are better than passing values.  Now I'm a little confused here.

Why is storing values in a `std::vector` is better than pointer? What difference 64-bit `int` makes?

Comment: "In my short C++ experience I've learned that references and pointers are better than passing values." - I'm afraid you've learned wrong.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Passing a reference is very frequently better than passing a value.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition since the advent of std::move and copy elision, passing by value is very often better (more efficient) than passing by reference. Certainly if the callee is to take ownership of the data.

Comment: @RichardHodges: It's that latter part that is key. Most of my functions do not take ownership. I'd wager that's true of most other people's functions, too. Either way, we cannot make a broad declaration on the topic, because (as usual) it depends!

Comment: Looks like you will have to unlearn a thing or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<T>` does make sense if `T` is a 64-bit integer, as its memory layout is just a cache-friendly *contiguous* array of `T`s:

```
+---------+ 
|T|T|...|T|
+---------+
```

On the other hand, `std::vector<T*>` is a more complex data structure, where you store the pointers contiguously; but the items (integers) pointed to are `not` contiguous in memory:

```
+--------------+ 
|T* | T*|...|T*|
+--------------+
 |   |       |
 \-> \->     \->
```

So, `vector<T*>` is much more *inefficient* and less cache-friendly than `vector<T>` for a simple integer `T`.

I would definitely suggest using `vector<T>` for a 64-bit integer `T`. *Why* would you need the additional level of indirection of `T*`?

Moreover, pay attention when storing *raw* pointers in STL containers. Raw *observing* pointers are fine; but raw *owning* pointers are a source of "leaktrocities", and you should consider storing *smart* owning pointers instead (e.g. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`). But, again, this doesn't make much sense for a simple 64-bit integer type.

Answer (score 3):

Passing and storing are two different things.

It's true that, when passing arguments, a reference is often desirable.

However, *storing* pointers and references is something you don't do unless you actually need to. It vastly complicates matters, requiring careful object lifetime management. If you don't need it, you just store values and let move semantics take care of the rest (this is particularly true of vectors because they take ownership of their elements).

Whether `std::vector<GA_Offset*>` is better than `std::vector<GA_Offset>` or not in this case completely depends on the application. It may be that the container is deliberately storing "handles" for some operational reason. We can't tell, because it depends on what the vector is supposed to do.